# html5 app with svg imags and layers: performance and layers

Tags: extjs, svg, mono, html5-canvas, raphael

We developed an application 15 years ago with .NET.
Right now we are thinking about recoding it.
Our ideal requeriments are:
1. Multiplatform: tablet and PC (Mac, Linux, Windows)
2. Hosted at our own server so we could sell the application as a SAAS
3. Develop some parts of the application for mobile devices
4. Use of third party components: datagrid, appointment schedule, graphical charts.

We think we should focus our efforts on web tecnnologies because:
One language for all platforms, even we could use some of our code for requirement 3 using a responsive web design, so we have requirements 1,2,3 out of the box.
Our favourite development tool would be extjs because of the components it provides (requirment 4).

But our big problem is.... we are not sure we could a graphical part of our application with html5/extjs:
There are 40 images we should import, ideally svg because the user should interact with them (click, drag and drop) so some other images could render inside the original ones, as layers.
For each image we can draw from 0 to 20 images over it, and whatever combination of them is possible so the total number of images could be huge without layers.

Any framework we could use? Maybe raphaeljs? Any example with layers? Tutorial examples are too simple and we're not sure about performance issues.

Maybe another option could be C# & mono? Basic knowledge about C# or WPF in our team but not with mono or implementint it as a SAAS. Maybe we could use xamarin?
Requirement4 could be implemented using a Telerik control or similar but we have no idea about compatibility issues (requirement 1).

Maybe we are too ambitious?

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with coding related questions. So you might ask your question on Stackoverflow's new sister site that deals with software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com  Good luck with your conversion! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS 4 supports SVG drawing out of the box: see [Ext.draw.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.draw.Component).